# How to login user to tty from ssh?

Tags: arch-linux, login, tty

I have booted up linux machine sitting at console login screen. Now I connect to that machine via ssh and I want to log user to displayed tty. Basically I want to bypass the login prompt in the console and go to the shell.

However what I do not want is auto-login on boot, I want to manually trigger the login via ssh.

How to do that?

Comment: Is this a systemd system?

Comment: yes (12 more charactes to go... sigh :/)

Comment: You would need to redirect the output of the ssh session to the console tty.

Answer (score 5):

`openvt` (a.k.a. `open`) executes a given program in a given `tty`. Default program is your shell. Default `tty` is the first available. If you want to use a specific `tty`, you have to ensure it is not already used (by `getty` or an X session for example). The best is to use the default and to switch to the terminal with the `-s` option.

```
# openvt -l -s
```

Comment: `Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console.` = make sure to use `sudo` because of the `#`

Comment: @aaa You are right, what the OP wants to do (access to a local console by bypassing the login shell) requires root privileges

Answer (score 0):

You can configure one getty for autologin, disable this one and start it via SSH:

`systemctl cat getty@tty4` gives you output like this (openSUSE Tumbleweed here):

```
[Service]
# the VT is cleared by TTYVTDisallocate
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear %I $TERM
Type=idle
Restart=always
RestartSec=0
UtmpIdentifier=%I
TTYPath=/dev/%I
TTYReset=yes
TTYVHangup=yes
TTYVTDisallocate=yes
KillMode=process
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
SendSIGHUP=yes
```

You have to override some of these settings:

```
systemctl cat getty@tty4

[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin username --noclear %I $TERM
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/chvt 4
KillMode=none
```

Then you disable it: `systemctl disable getty@tty4`

Via SSH you run:

```
systemctl start getty@tty4 ; systemctl stop getty@tty4
```

The `stop` makes sure that you can actually logout (otherwise the shell would be restarted).